# Value does not change in admin dashboard and html template, view function shows the correct one

Tags: python, django, django-views

Value does not change in admin dahboard and html template that has a tag of the value, inrthe view function where the change happens,it print the correct value that was changed (order.status)

```
def chef_order(request):
chef = request.user.vendor
orders = chef.orders.all()

if 'btnform1' in request.POST:
    orderid = request.POST.get("orderid")
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=int(orderid))
    sts = 'confirmed'
    order.status = "confirmed"
    print(order.get_status_display())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
order = Order.objects.get(pk=int(orderid))
```

This returns an instance object of the database record.  However, it's not the record itself.  When you update the field on the instance, you need to save it back to the database.

```
order.status = "confirmed"
order.save()
```